# Assume that u∙v=5, ||u||=6, and ||v||=8. What is the value of 1u∙(8u-v)?

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

I have been working on a homework problem like this for a while now and cannot seem to get the correct answer. This question is not the original question. I changed the values and hope that someone could help me with the process so I can then apply it to what I am actually working on. I am not sure where I went wrong and what to try next. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: $a\mathbf{u} \cdot b\mathbf{u} =ab||\mathbf{u}||^2$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
1 \vec u \cdot (8 \vec u - \vec v)
&=& 8\vec u \cdot \vec u - \vec u \cdot \vec v \\
&=& 8\left\|\vec u\right\|^2 - \vec u \cdot \vec v \\
&=& 8(6)^2 - (5) \\
&=& 283
\end{array}$$

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for you help. I tried this and it worked. :)

Comment: @trekkie1996 If an answer helped you, please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). That way, the question gets removed from the 'Unanswered' queue. I strongly suggest that you do this for your other questions too.

Answer (score 0):

multiplying out we get $$8u^2-uv=8|u|^2-uv=8\cdot 36-5=?$$

Comment: 283! I got the answer correct now, but thank you for your help :)